# Filter with radio buttons with different values (AngularJS)?

Tags: angularjs, filter, radio-button

I have a list of items which I want to filter with radio buttons, here's an example of my array:

```
$scope.items = [
  {
    "name":"person 1",
    "section":"one",
    "job":false
  },
  {
    "name":"person 2",
    "section":"two",
    "job":true
  },
  {
    "name":"person 3",
    "section":"one",
    "job":false
  },
  {
    "name":"person 4",
    "section":"one",
    "job":true
  }
];
```

In my HTML, I have an **ng-repeat** list which I want to filter with **radio buttons**:

```
<div class="menu">
   <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="filteradio.section" value="">
      <p>All</p>
   </label>

   <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="filteradio.section" value="one">
      <p>Section 1</p>
   </label>

   <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="filteradio.section" value="two">
      <p>Section 2</p>
   </label>

   <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="filteradio.job" value="true">
      <p>People with job</p>
   </label>
</div>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Section</td>
      <td>Job</td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filteradio:strict">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.section}}</td>
      <td ng-if="item.job">yes</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that **the last radio button** won't work, because when I select the buttons with *"filteradio.section"* they work fine, but once I click in the *"filteradio.job"* the other radio buttons stay checked!
I tried adding the same "**name** atribute" to all radio buttons but this way once I click *"filteradio.job"* all items dissapear.
How can I filter them all by "section" and also by "if they have a job or not"? Is there an easier way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included a working example below, but I'll go through some noteworthy points:

- All your radio inputs should bind to the same `ng-model` if the options aren't mutually exclusive, otherwise you can end up in states where multiple radio inputs are selected
- To implement the filtering you need on the table:

  - Keep track of a filter structure that stores the item property and value to filter by
  - Use `ng-change` to update this filter structure as necessary
  - Use a custom filter comparator that draws upon the filter structure
- Take note some radio inputs use `ng-value` instead of `value`, the latter values will always be interpreted as string literals

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    var radioFilter = {
      prop: 'section',
      value: null,
    };
    $scope.items = [
      {
        name: 'person 1',
        section: 'one',
        job: false,
      },
      {
        name: 'person 2',
        section: 'two',
        job: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'person 3',
        section: 'one',
        job: false,
      },
      {
        name: 'person 4',
        section: 'one',
        job: true,
      }
    ];
    $scope.radio = null;
    $scope.radioChanged = function (prop) {
      radioFilter = {
        prop: prop,
        value: $scope.radio,
      };
    };
    $scope.filterByRadio = function (item) {
      return $scope.radio === null || item[radioFilter.prop] === $scope.radio;
    };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
     <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="radio" ng-change="radioChanged('section')" ng-value="null"> All
     </label>
     <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="radio" ng-change="radioChanged('section')" value="one"> Section 1
     </label>
     <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="radio" ng-change="radioChanged('section')" value="two"> Section 2
     </label>
     <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="radio" ng-change="radioChanged('job')" ng-value="true"> People with job
     </label>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Section</td>
      <td>Job</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filterByRadio">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.section }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.job ? "yes" : "" }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular@1.7.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Amazing dude, just amazing! Thank you a lot, I'm still kinda new with Angular and you just saved me, this works pretty well!